# AngularJS http posts multiple times

Tags: angularjs

I'm going crazy with this after searching for two days, I really hope someone can help.

I have an AngularJS project using gulp. From here I call a basic method to execute and http post to my c# API like so:

`var $http({
        url: serverAddress + '/api/general/sendemail',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: '',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }`

Whenever I call this method (or any method using $http), it seems to execute the call twice on the server.

The strange thing is that it only does it from AngularJS.

If I run it on postman, it executes only once.

Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you think this executes the call twice on the server? BTW, this code is incomplete.

Comment: Can you provide the part of code where this $http method is invoked? Is it a Controller or a Service?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback, guys.

It seems that it was only when I was serving the page from gulp that it was behaving this way. I uploaded to IIS and it worked as expected.

Regarding your comments, it was sending the email twice every time I clicked the send button, and it was a controller and not a service.

Thanks